# Convert Radio Button Value to bool

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to convert the value of the radio button when selected to be 'out' to a variable which will then be passed as true or false.

But it always returns false i have tried many different ways and this is where i am.

```
if (rad_Security_Risk.SelectedItem.Value == "NO")
{
    if (bool.TryParse(rad_Security_Risk.SelectedValue, out risk))
    {
        risk = false;
        obj.Security_Risk = risk;
    }
}

if (rad_Security_Risk.SelectedItem.Value == "YES")
{
    if (bool.TryParse(rad_Security_Risk.SelectedValue, out risk))
    {
        risk = true;
        obj.Security_Risk = risk;
    }
}
```

When I select YES it always is false?

Comment: Why do you want to parse "YES" to a `bool` when you already know that it's true since you're in the `if`?

Comment: because this is what my manager wants me to do. He has made me change the db to be a bit and wants me to convert it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code makes no sense as it is - it performs lots of redundant assignments. Also, Boolean.TryParse cannot parse "YES" and "NO" to `true` and `false`. It just doesn't do that as the [examples in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.parse.aspx) makes clear. It will only parse a string that corresponds to [Boolean.TrueString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.truestring.aspx) or [Boolean.FalseString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.falsestring.aspx)

It can be enormously simplified as so:

```
if (rad_Security_Risk.SelectedItem.Value == "NO")
{
    obj.Security_Risk = false;
}
else if (rad_Security_Risk.SelectedItem.Value == "YES")
{
    obj.Security_Risk = true;
}
else 
{
    // Is there a possibility that the value can be something
    // other than YES or NO?
    throw new Exception ("Undefined behaviour!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It always seems simpler when somebody else looks at it. The instructions i got was to use tryparse to convert the value. So ended up with lots of different ways except the obvious.

Answer (score 1):

f you are only want to have two value , should have 'true' and 'false', it's enough . if you have more value or more type ,you can use the type of byte or int .... the you should use the if ... else ... or switch ... case ...

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblList" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="True" Value="True" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="False" Value="False"></asp:ListItem>
 </asp:RadioButtonList>

 var a = Convert.ToBoolean(rblList.SelectedValue);
```

or

```
var a = Convert.ToInt16(rblList.SelectedValue);
var retValue = string.Empty;
switch (a)
{
    case 0:
        //"you want have"
        break;
    case 1:
        //"you want have"
        break;
    case 2:
        //"you want have"
        break;
    default:
        //"you want have"
        break;
}
```

or

```
    if (a == 0)
    {
        //"you want have"
    }
    else if (a == 1)
    {
        //"you want have"
    }
    else if (a == 2)
    {
        //"you want have"
    }
    else
    {
        //"you want have"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblTest"  runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"  >
                <asp:ListItem Value="0">
                    No
                </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">
                    Yes
                </asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Then you can used your code bool.TryParse and also check you item using SelectedItem.Text

Answer (score 0):

You can't parse `"YES"` to `true` or `"NO"` to `false` As Habib pointed out you have to use

`True,true` for boolean `true` 
    `False,false` for boolean `false` when parsing

Use this code instead

```
        if (rad_Security_Risk.SelectedItem.Value == "NO")
        {
            if (bool.TryParse("False", out risk))
            {
                risk = false;
                obj.Security_Risk = risk;
            }
        }

        if (rad_Security_Risk.SelectedItem.Value == "YES")
        {
            if (bool.TryParse("True", out risk))
            {
                risk = true;
                obj.Security_Risk = risk;
            }
        }
```